# jQuery load causes load of the whole page in the Opera browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

Here is the part of my page with the problem:

```
<div id="notice_box" class="center">
  <div id="notice_cont"></div>
<script>
    function notice(more)
    {
        $('#notice_cont').load('notice.php?more_notice='+more);
    }
</script>
</div>
    <div id="notice_box_foot">
   <img src="images/notice-box-bl.png" class="left">
   <img src="images/notice-box-br.png" class="right">
 </div>
</div>
```

It gets called like this:

```
<a style="margin-right:5px;" class="right" href="javascript:notice(3);"><img src="images/not-less.png" /></a>
```

The script is supposed to fill `#notice_cont` with `notice.php`... rather it fills the whole page with it... works fine in all browsers except Opera! There are no errors either.

Comment: So im guessing that no one can shed some light in this..?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing that `<a>` tag:

```
<a style='margin-right: 5px' class='right' href='#' onclick='notice(3); return false'><img ...></a>
```

to make sure that the default behavior of the `<a>` tag itself does not happen.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using, and what version of Opera?

Comment: Latest version of Opera v10.63 and jQuery v1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried validating the output of notice.php? Since you haven't shown this markup I'm just guessing here, but I'd guess that the markup is malformed and Opera thus doesn't insert it correctly.